# matplotlib: adding padding/offset to polar plots tick labels

Tags: matplotlib, label, axis-labels, radial

Is there a way to increase the padding/offset of the polar plot tick labels (theta)?

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, grid

# make a square figure
fig = figure(figsize=(2, 2))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True, axisbg='#d5de9c')
ax.set_yticklabels([])

r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
theta = 2*np.pi*r
ax.plot(theta, r, color='#ee8d18', lw=3)
ax.set_rmax(2.0)
show()
```

I'd like to have theta tick labels further away from the polar plot so they don't overlap.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all; seeing as how you have specified the `figsize` to be (2,2) and having the `ax` occupy 80 % of both the width and height, you have *very little* space left over to pad the ticklabels. This could cause the ticklabels to be "cut off" at the figure's egdes. This can easily be "fixed" by either

- Specifying bigger `figsize`
- Make the `ax` occupy less space on the (2,2) sized figure
- Use smaller fontsize for the ticklabels

or any combination of these. Another, in my opinion better, solution to this "problem" is to use a subplot rather than specifying the `Axes`'s bounds;

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True, axisbg='#d5de9c')
```

as this makes it possible to use the method `tight_layout()` which automatically configures the figure layout to nicely include all elements.

Then over to the real problem at hand; the padding. On a `PolarAxes` you can set, among other things, the radial placement of the theta-ticks. This is done by specifying the fraction of the polar axes radius where you want the ticklabels to be placed as an argument to the `frac` parameter of the `PolarAxes`'s [`set_thetagrids()`](http://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html?highlight=set_thetagrids#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes.set_thetagrids) method. The argument should be a fraction of the axes' radius where you want the ticklabels placed. I.e. for `frac` < 1 the ticklabels will be placed inside the axes, while for `frac` > 1 they will be placed outside the axes.

Your code could then be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, grid, tight_layout
# make a square figure
fig = figure(figsize=(2, 2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True, axisbg='#d5de9c')
ax.set_yticklabels([])

r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
theta = 2*np.pi*r
ax.plot(theta, r, color='#ee8d18', lw=3)
ax.set_rmax(2.0)

# tick locations
thetaticks = np.arange(0,360,45)

# set ticklabels location at 1.3 times the axes' radius
ax.set_thetagrids(thetaticks, frac=1.3)

tight_layout()

show()
```

[image: PolarAxes with frac=1.3]

You should try different values for `frac` to find a value that is best suited for your needs.

If you don't specify a value to the parameter `frac` as above, i.e. `frac` has default value `None`, the code outputs a plot as below. Notice how the radius of the plot is bigger, as the ticklabels don't "occupy as much space" as in the example above.

[image: PolarAxes with frac=None]

Comment: Do you know what the default `frac` is?

Comment: @Annan From [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ff31d67a8103620221a3eeadeb985e8268a7d934/doc/users/whats_new.rst#enhancements-to-polar-plot) it seems `frac` is deprecated. "[...] Consequently, the `frac` argument to .PolarAxes.set_thetagrids is no longer applied. Tick padding can be modified with the `pad` argument to .Axes.tick_params or .Axis.set_tick_params."

Comment: @Annan But to answer your question, it used to be `1.1`.

Comment: For current versions of matplotlib the following works:

`ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)`

Answer (score 7):

[As of matplotlib 2.1.0](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.1.0.html#enhancements-to-polar-plot), the functionality of the original answer is [now deprecated](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9744/) - polar axes now obey to the parameters of `ax.tick_params`:

```
ax.tick_params(pad=123)
```

should do the trick.