# Offset matplotlib `ticklabels` from axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

In some (rather small) figures using `polar=True`, the `ticklabels` are overlapping with the axis. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=[2,2])
fig.subplots_adjust(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8)
ax = pl.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_yticks([])
```

Creates:

[image]

Is it possible to set an offset between the axis and labels, i.e. move `180` a bit to the left, `0` to the right, et cetera? I prefer to set it per `subplot`, as I have some other `subplots` in the same figure which don't require the `ticklabel` offset.

Comment: See [adding padding/offset to polar plots tick labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159668/matplotlib-adding-padding-offset-to-polar-plots-tick-labels). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that perfectly answers my question, didn't see that one. I voted to close my question as a duplicate of that one...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `set_thetagrids` method of `PolarAxes` class, which - aside from allowing you to define the properties of the theta coordinate grid - can set the radial offset of the tick labels by scaling the `frac` argument. See the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html#module-matplotlib.projections.polar) for more info. Here's your modified example for the same font and figure sizes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=[2,2])
fig.subplots_adjust(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8)
ax = pl.subplot(111, polar=True)

# if you want to preserve the old tick degrees
old_ticks = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs() / np.pi * 180
ax.set_thetagrids(old_ticks, frac=1.3)
ax.set_yticks([])
pl.show()
```

[image: polar ticks]

Edit: the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159668/matplotlib-adding-padding-offset-to-polar-plots-tick-labels) linked by @nostradamus in the OP comment section is more detailed than my own. I recommend taking a look at it.

Comment: Yes, I agree, didn't see that question, and it perfectly answers my question.