# Radar / Polar plot labels intersect with plot self

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, polar-coordinates

I have a simple problem
I wanted to create a radar plot as in the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/specialty_plots/radar_chart.html). Since i need only a single radar and i want the default colors i choose to modify the example.

the first steps worked out well. but when changing the labels on the radar i encountered a problem. The names i use are to long and crossing that plot itself.

[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159668/matplotlib-adding-padding-offset-to-polar-plots-tick-labels) had a similar problem but the solution at that moment is depreciated.
In one of the comments said that current method is `set_pad()`.

Till no i workout at least a lot of solutions that don't work... The two error i got most are

```
AttributeError: type object '...' has no attribute 'set_pad'
```

and

```
AttributeError: 'RadarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute '...'
```

The code i currently have is this:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D


def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    """
    Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes.

    This function creates a RadarAxes projection and registers it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_vars : int
        Number of variables for radar chart.
    frame : {'circle', 'polygon'}
        Shape of frame surrounding axes.

    """
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):

        name = 'radar'
        # use 1 line segment to connect specified points
        RESOLUTION = 1

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # rotate plot such that the first axis is at the top
            self.set_theta_zero_location('N')

        def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            return super().fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super().plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.append(x, x[0])
                y = np.append(y, y[0])
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            # The Axes patch must be centered at (0.5, 0.5) and of radius 0.5
            # in axes coordinates.
            if frame == 'circle':
                return Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                return RegularPolygon((0.5, 0.5), num_vars,
                                      radius=.5, edgecolor="k")
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return super()._gen_axes_spines()
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                # spine_type must be 'left'/'right'/'top'/'bottom'/'circle'.
                spine = Spine(axes=self,
                              spine_type='circle',
                              path=Path.unit_regular_polygon(num_vars))
                # unit_regular_polygon gives a polygon of radius 1 centered at
                # (0, 0) but we want a polygon of radius 0.5 centered at (0.5,
                # 0.5) in axes coordinates.
                spine.set_transform(Affine2D().scale(.5).translate(.5, .5)
                                    + self.transAxes)
                return {'polar': spine}
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta


def example_data():
    # The following data is from the Denver Aerosol Sources and Health study.
    # See doi:10.1016/j.atmosenv.2008.12.017
    #
    # ...
    data = [
        ['Sulfate', 'Nitrate', 'a long string', 'Abbr.', 'a string', 'b string', 'another longs string', 's str', 'sh str'],
        ('Basecase', [
            [0.88, 0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.00, 0.06, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.07, 0.95, 0.04, 0.05, 0.00, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.85, 0.19, 0.05, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.21, 0.12, 0.98, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.74, 0.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]])
    ]
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 9
    theta = radar_factory(N)  # , frame='polygon')

    data = example_data()
    title = data[1][0]
    spoke_labels = data.pop(0)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='radar')

    # ax.set_rgrids([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
    ax.set_title(title, weight='bold', size='medium', position=(0.5, 1.5), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
    case_data = data[0][1]
    caseiter = [0, 1, 2]
    for d in zip(case_data):
        print(d)
        ax.plot(theta, d[0])
        ax.fill(theta, d[0], alpha=0.25)
    ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)  # , frac=1.5)
    # ax.axis.ThetaTick.set_pad(20)  # in pixels
    # ax.axis.XTick.set_pad(20)  # in pixels
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

    # add legend relative to top-left plot
    labels = ('Factor 1', 'Factor 2', 'Factor 3', 'Factor 4', 'Factor 5')
    legend = ax.legend(labels, loc=(0.9, .95), labelspacing=0.1, fontsize='small')

    fig.text(0.5, 1, 'Experiences',
             horizontalalignment='center', color='black', weight='bold',
             size='large')

    plt.show()
```

This is current result.

[image: radar width text]

To me it don't matter if all labels get a offset OR that the alignment of the text starts at the circle.

Comment: perhaps something like `ax.tick_params(pad=2)` (not sure what pad would work here, try experimenting with it)

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas (these can be combined as suitable for your data):

- right-align the ticks at the left, and left-align the ticks at the right (leave the top and bottom center-aligned)
- replace spaces in the labels with newlines, so the tick will be spread over multiple lines
- optionally move the legend if it would overlap with some tick labels
- call `plt.tight_layout()` at the end, so the legend and the tick labels will fit nicely into the figure

In the given code, I changed function `set_varlabels()` as follows:

```py
        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            labels_with_newlines = [l.replace(' ', '\n') for l in labels]
            _lines, texts = self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels_with_newlines)
            half = (len(texts) - 1) // 2
            for t in texts[1:half]:
                t.set_horizontalalignment('left')
            for t in texts[-half + 1:]:
                t.set_horizontalalignment('right')
```

I also used `loc=(1.2, 0.95)` for the legend and called `plt.tight_layout()` at the end.

It then looks like:

[image: radar plot with realigned labels]

Comment: I think it would be but i used the command but i tried the command of @tmdavison first and that works out.